# 2022 Benelli TNT 135

Tags: motorcycle, cel, wont-stay-running

Hello I am having issues with my bike starting. It only wants to start when it is jumped off and will ride pretty decent but shuts off if you slow down after a while to park. Also the engine light has come on. Any information helps. Thank you!

Comment: If it is still under warranty, take it to the dealer! Trying to fix it yourself might void the warranty.

Comment: Appreciate this! I am currently looking for my warranty paperwork. The bike is brand new only 66 miles on it so it should not be having this problem.

Comment: The engine light on a Benelli TNT 135 can also be caused by a problem with the oxygen sensor, exhaust system, or other emissions-related components.
If you have recently installed any aftermarket parts on the bike maybe exhaust?